# default css empty selector?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a CSS tag that can provide an id for text.  I want to be able to modify the text with javascript, so i need something like:

```
<texttag id="the_id">the text</texttag>
```

All the other tags i've tried affect the formatting one way or another.  For example it would be used in a sentence, such as:

```
You live in <texttag id="town_id">Newmarket</texttag>.  Thats a nice town.
```

And it would display as:

You live in Newmarket.  Thats a nice town.

But I would have the ability to modify Newmarket with the id town_id ..

See what i mean?  If I use `<p> or <div>` the text wraps..

Comment: I think you've confused CSS selectors and HTML elements (tags).  HTML elements are the things in your web page with angle brackets.  A CSS selector is something that goes in your stylesheet, one of which can be a HTML element (ie, `a { color:red; }` makes all `<a>` elements red), among other things.  [More info here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref).

Answer (score 4):

The `<span>` HTML tag has a display of `inline` and has no presentational nor semantic meaning attached to it.  You can use CSS to apply whatever styles you'd like or script to modify the element's contents.

```
This sentence has <span id="whatever">text</span>.
```

To change contents:

```
docuent.getElementById('whatever').innerHTML('changed text');
```

To style that specific element:

```
#whatever { font-weight:bold; }
```

Also, you may want to read about [the difference between block and inline elements](http://cat.xula.edu/tutorials/html/versus.php).  (And an [expanded explanation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Document_body_elements).)  (`<p>` and `<div>` are block; `<span>` is inline.)